# Instrument and leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-warning

I have an application and I am profiling it. I am quite new to instrument and I am quite new ios developer as well. I am working with ios6 and I have a very unusual leak. I create a category on UIImage and added helper methods to return the image for using capinsets. My category looks like this,

```
@implementation UIImage (Helpers)

+(UIImage*)resizableImageWithName:(NSString *)imageName andCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    return [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
}

@end
```

The instrument shows 3/4 leaks in this area, the same place and I could not figure out the reason for it. Is it that, I have to release the new image I created inside the category, if I release it what am I going to return ? Could any one please explain the reason that I am leaking memory here.

And I used it like this;

```
[self.progressView setTrackImage:[UIImage resizableImageWithName:@"progress_bar_background.png" andCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)]];
```

Is there something wrong in using this method in this way ?

Comment: Have you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu in Xcode)? Especially if non-ARC code, it finds many leaks and better indicates the particular lines of code that actually caused the problem (as opposed to just showing you where they were allocated, as sergio points out).

Comment: This is ARC enabled code and I used the analyze from product menu in xcode itself.

Comment: If you're running ARC, then I don't get your comment about needing to `release`, since you can't do that in ARC. Regardless, as an aside, I notice you're using `imageNamed` which caches images. It's not generally characterized as a leak, per se, but it definitely will generate allocations that are not generally released. You can always try `imageWithContentsOfFile`, using a path you derive from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource ...]`.

Comment: I mean to set the object nil. If the image objects take memory, is it a good idea to set it to nil as soon as I finish assigning image to certain view ?

Comment: If you use `imageNamed` the memory won't be deallocated, anyway. But if Instruments is reporting actual leaks (not just growing allocations), then it's probably something else. Might be worth trying `imageWithContentsOfFile`, regardless, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that Instruments shows you is the place where the leaked memory is allocated -- not necessarily the place where the memory is leaked. Indeed your method is correct as to memory management.

Thus, you better inspect how you handle the returned `UIImage` object... possibly, if this hint does not help you finding the leak cause, post some more code.

Comment: without knowing how progressView implements `trackImage` I can´t say anything specific. Keep in mind anyway that the static analyzer sometimes is not correct in identifying leaks, because it uses a heuristics for that. If you want to be sure, run your app under Instruments/Leaks.